# What's the origin of the shell variable BASH_SOURCE?

Tags: bash

I have seen the variable `BASH_SOURCE` in various scripts, but I don't understand how it works and where it comes from. For example, this command returns the current directory `.`:

```
dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
.
```

However, `BASH_SOURCE` itself seems to be undefined, all the following commands return nothing:

```
echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
echo $BASH_SOURCE
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

Comment: `man bash, /BASH_SOURCE`

Comment: The behavior of `dirname` has nothing to do with BASH_SOURCE.  Try `dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` and `dirname ""`

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. If anyone put that into an answer, I could accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

This variable is available when a script is being sourced or executed by bash. It contains nothing in an interactive session.

From the manual:

```
  BASH_SOURCE
      An array variable whose members are the source filenames  where  the
      corresponding  shell  function  names in the FUNCNAME array variable
      are defined.  The shell function ${FUNCNAME[$i]} is defined  in  the
      file ${BASH_SOURCE[$i]} and called from ${BASH_SOURCE[$i+1]}.
```

Practical example:

```
$ for i in a b c d ; do cat $i; echo ----- ;done
```

---

```
echo a: ${BASH_SOURCE[*]}
source b
```

---

```
echo b: ${BASH_SOURCE[@]}
. c
```

---

```
echo c: ${BASH_SOURCE[@]}
echo ...
bash d
```

---

```
echo d: ${BASH_SOURCE[@]}
```

---

Output:

```
$ . a
a: a
b: b a
c: c b a
...
d: d
```

---

Bonus

dirname gives you a dot because that's what it's supposed to do when called with the empty string as input.

```
$ dirname ""
.
```